# Webpage slides up when soft keyboard is active

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a chat page layout web application with input at the bottom, and a header at the top. when the input is in focus the page moves up.

These headers are present in my page for preventing zoom or other unwanted behaviour.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">`

[image: Representation of my question]

When trying to resize the window using javascript using `window.innerHeight` but that doesn't work as well even with a `setTimeout()`

Is there a workaround for the browser to not pan the whole page up, or resize with subtracting height of keyboard?

Comment: What is the outcome you expect?

Comment: The outcome is in the middle of the image I've attached.

Comment: Is `position: fixed;` not an option? The resources of your code that you've given are *very* limited.

Comment: If `position:fixed;` isn't desirable to have all the time, one solution I have used is to add and remove the class on input focus and blur respectively.

Comment: @Sidharth Can you add a snippet I can use to comprehend and edit your code?

Comment: `position: fixed;` does not help because browsers try to push the whole page up and we don't get any parameter changes.

Comment: @Sparky I'll have a snippet added to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Starting in Safari 10, the keyboard height doesn't affect `window.innerHeight`. [Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Articles/Safari_10_0.html):

> Safari and WKWebView on iOS 10 do not update the window.innerHeight property when the keyboard is shown.

As you've found, not only does this make correctly sizing an element to the display area quite difficult, but there is no `resize` event when the keyboard is opened.

Because the keyboard slides the entire page out the top of the viewport, you may be able to calculate the display height using the difference between the window's height and the page's `scrollTop` property. To detect when the keyboard is open or closed, listen for the `onfocus` and `onblur` events on your input.

```
var myInput = document.getElementById( "your-input-field-id" );
var myContainer = document.getElementById( "your-container-id" );

myInput.addEventListener( 'onfocus', function() {
    var displayHeight = window.innerHeight - myContainer.scrollTop;
    myContainer.style.height = displayHeight + "px";
}, true );

myInput.addEventListener( 'onblur', function() {
    myContainer.style.height = "100%";
}, true );
```

Comment: This almost works but the keyboard moves up the keyboard even more when I start typing, is there anyway that I can stop that?

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your code it's difficult to say what the issue is. The container element should be the highest encapsulating element in the DOM tree with `height: 100%`, this may be the `body` element.

Answer (score 1):

make a clone of header main element, and put it on the top of if whenever user focus into input would be a simplest answer.

```
$('#example').clone().addClass('cloned').prependTo('body');
```

However you must add unique class to that element, and give below css to that class,

```
.cloned {
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    z-index:'give highest z-index';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `<div> root </div>` inside another `<div> your_element </div>`

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to use the  `position:fixed; top:0;`  on the header without creating clones.